# Who will be resurrected at the time of Mashiach?

Tags: messiah, resurrection-of-the-dead

We've all heard about the resurrection of the dead at the coming of the Mashiach. But who will be resurrected is a question many people have. I've heard that only the tzadikim will resurrect and that if you do Teshuva you will be present for his arrival. I've also heard that about a third of the world will survive Gog Magog and be present at the time he comes. I've also heard a more profound opinion that says that your soul will be resurrected in the body of the most tzadik that hosted your soul.

Who will be resurrected when the Mashiach comes?

Comment: Note that it's very possible the resurrection will not occur at the coming of the Mashiach but much later on. That doesn't really change your question though.

Comment: You're touching on the question of what is Tchi'as HaMeisim and when/what is Olam HaBo, and related discussions that we don't know the answers. There are Mishnayot that discuss who has no part in Tchi'as HaMeisim or Olam HaBo.